# Couch-Pouch Production Configuration

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I am using Couch Pouch for offline sync in hybrid mobile app using ionic framework.
I have big docs in couch db, each doc is around 10,000 lines (only text) and around 1000 docs.
I have used filter on couch db by using design doc which will sync at max 3 docs with the Client Mobile App.
Now, when sync starts at mobile app, it takes 9 minutes to sync 3 docs in mobile app. This is quite weird that it took 9 minutes to fetch 3 docs.

Can this be configuration issue, I might be missing some configuration on Couch Db ?

Comment: Can you share the design document. It would be helpful.